# Converting expression to be compatible with FetchXML report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I've converted an SSRS report from SQL to FETCHXML that was used by on-premises CRM 2011.

Now the report is using CRM 2013 as the data source.

In the old version of this report we had this expression:

`=String.Format(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1033), chrw(123)&"0"&chrw(125)&" "&chrw(40)&"Count"&chrw(58)&" "&chrw(123)&"1"&chrw(125)&chrw(41), IIf(IsNothing(Fields!stepname.Value), "Not specified", Fields!stepname.Value), CInt(Count("")).ToString(First(Fields!NumberFormat_0_Precision.Value, "DSNumberAndCurrencyInfo"), Code.GetCultureInfo()))`

I need to update this expression to be compatible with the online instance, and I am not understanding what it's supposed to do.

I was told that the cultureinfo is static and will not change, so it can be hard coded.

**For starters, what does Cint(Count("")) do?** I do not understand what this expression does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can provide the explanation for 
`IIF(IsNothing(Fields!stepname.Value), "Not specified", Fields!stepname.Value), CInt(Count("")).ToString(First(Fields!NumberFormat_0_Precision.Value, "DSNumberAndCurrencyInfo"), Code.GetCultureInfo()))`

not as for why is it done the way it is but for what is possible as output

```
1) CInt(Count("") -
```

This will give the current groups row count if it is in the group total row and if there is group if no group present then it will always give 1 as current row count

```
2) ToString(First(Fields!NumberFormat_0_Precision.Value, "DSNumberAndCurrencyInfo"), Code.GetCultureInfo())  -
```

In here two parameters

a) `First(Fields!NumberFormat_0_Precision.Value)` it will be the format in which  the number should be formatted

b) Second one will be something from 
[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) system class. But that is coming from your custom code of the report. You should check your custom code for the report.

```
3) IIF(IsNothing(Fields!stepname.Value), "Not specified", Fields!stepname.Value)
```

Here the expression checking if the `stepname` column has the value or null if null then then return `Not specified` otherwise the value.

So I am not sure why this is done this way. You can make changes if you look at the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd255237.aspx) then you will notice you can pass the scope so it will not confuse the hell out of the next developer. Then If your custom function `GetCultureInfo()`  is just returning the `CultureInfo` without any conditions or changes then you can directly pass it in the expression as below.

```
 .ToString(First(Fields!NumberFormat_0_Precision.Value, "DSNumberAndCurrencyInfo"), new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

You can get more info on [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Next part is starting of the expression as

```
New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1033)
```

In .NET Framework 3.5, you can use reflection to force specific calls to properties and methods to use English (United States) data format (locale ID 1033). So it just for using the data format.

```
chrw(123)&"0"&chrw(125)&" "&chrw(40)&"Count"&chrw(58)&" "&chrw(123)&"1"&chrw(125)&chrw(41)
```

And this is all used for displaying different characters using the char code more on this [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46(v=vs.90).aspx)

So all this big expression is basically used for the formatting the string value in particular format specified in database an with the use of the some conditions.

Comment: Thanks very much! Im trying to figure out how to do a row count in a way that works for a fetchxml report